# Keep protect server from stress test or from V-Users

Tags: security, iis, jmeter, windows-server-2012, loadrunner

I am worried about the trespassers on my site , so my question is that how to keep my server protected from stress test .

I am an Performance tester, so we have a separate server **Production Like Server** . There we used to do all kind of **"Performance testing"**  like Stress, Load,and  Endurance Test etc . So here by I want to know how to block a trespasser from putting load on my **Live server** (Rather than genuine users ) from a particular IP , or how to block the **V-USERS**(Virtual Users) (LoadRunner/Jmeter/or any other load testing tool) .

We have the servers : **IIS 2012 / Famrwork 4.5**

Kindly let me know if the question is not clear to you .

Comment: It is server configuration to allow/block specific IPs. better ask the question to right audience here http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Dear Naveen , you are not getting the question , its not about to block a specific User(IP), concern is about blocking V-users, those who can put load , or can damage my server .

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a firewall rule configuration question.  Once you understand what your natural load looks like then consider a rule which automatically blocks IP addresses which are beyond 3/4 standard deviations in traffic.  Bots and performance tests are fairly easy to identify because of the small number of IP addresses generating large amounts of request traffic.

Odds are if you pulled your HTTP request logs today and did a count of requests by IP you would then find quickly that some of the IP addresses fall very quickly to the top of the number of requests.  Examine the user agent strings carefully.  You will likely find patterns.  Use WhoIS to look up the networks that this large users by IP address are a part of.   Engage firewall rules to block or frustrate (random blocking with a 503 for up to 30 minutes at a time, demand captcha, etc...) the appropriate IP addresses.

I know some sites which block all cloud providers because of bots.  I know others which block whole country subnets because of abuse.  I also know some companies that corral the bots and load testers with 503's & Captchas with a great deal of success.  DDOS are much harder as these typically involve hundreds/if not thousands or tens of thousands of hosts.  The requests, however, tend to be substantially similar.  If you can ID them early and you have a CDN, then the web application firewall at your CDN can be a savior to keep the load off of your origin servers